# How to fuzzy match a routing path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router v5, and I wonder how can I match all children of `/add` but `/add/..` in one path. For example `/add_a` ,`/add`, `/add123` etc.

I've tried `<Route path="/add*" element={<div>TEST</div>} />`, but I got a warn that `Route path "/add*" will be treated as if it were "/add/*"`.

```
<Routes>
 <Route path="/add*" element={<div>TEST</div>} />
</Routes>
```

reference:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string

Comment: I think you should use `regex`...

Comment: It is unclear as what path you want to match. Do you want to match just `/add_a` and `add` or it can be anything followed by `_`? Like: `add_b`, `add_ajldadla`, etc.? Or is you want to match all its children routes like `/add/...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually using React-Router v6 according to the code and warning. React-Router v6 removed path regular expressions. You can read more about it in ["What Happened to Regexp Routes Paths?"](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-regexp-routes-paths).

I suggest you use route path `"/:add/*"` and regular expression `/^add.*$/` to:

1. Assign the dynamic path segment to the `add` parameter
2. Wildcard splat `"*"` to allow descendent route matching
3. Use the regular expression to test that `add` parameter value in the routed component and conditionally redirect/render the specific content

Example:

```
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const TestComponent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { add } = useParams();

  const match = add.match(/^add.*$/);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!match) navigate(-1);
  }, [match]);

  return match ? <div>TEST</div> : null;
};
```

```
<Routes>
  ....
  <Route path="/:add/*" element={<TestComponent />} />
</Routes>
```

If you intended to use React-Router v5 then ensure you have the proper version installed:

```
npm install react-router-dom@5
```

And use the correct components and API:

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Switch>
  {/* more specific routes */}
  <Route path="/add*" component={TestComponent} />
  {/* less specific routes */}
</Switch>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this `/add[^/]+` this will match all but except the second "/"

This means `/add_somethinghere` is matches
[image]

but `/add_somethinghere/extrathing` is not match
[image]

Try the playground here https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/

PS: The path in `react-router.v5` is using [path-to-regexp@^1.7.0](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0?tab=readme-ov-file#live-demo) as it was mentioned in https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string
The `Express Route Tester` is a demo of path-to-regexp

Comment: OP is not using an Express router so this answer doesn't appear to be valid or relevant.

Comment: I don't think so. The path in `react-router` v5 is using [path-to-regexp@^1.7.0](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0?tab=readme-ov-file#live-demo) as it was mentioned in 
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string